# Place one button below another in ConstraintLayout if they can't fit on screen

Tags: android, responsive-design, android-constraintlayout

I would like to place buttons horizontally on large screens and vertically on small screens (if they can't fit in screen resolution). Can I do it by using ConstraintLayout without creating two layouts in xml which depend on screen resolution?
I don't know how can I setup "constraints" for that behaviour?

[image: NOW IT WORKS LIKE THIS]

It is my layout in xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
       android:id="@+id/button5"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="First button"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button3" />

    <Button
       android:id="@+id/button3"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Second button"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button5"
       app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: you set static width height for button ?

Comment: Buttons have width and height on "wrap_content". I've added xml also to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to do that with just `ConstraintLayout`. It does not provide you with a way to create sort of a `linebreak` for `Views` in a chain.

There are multiple libraries that can easily let to do that. But you will have to introduce another layout. E.g. [`android-flowlayout`](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout).